# Restoring the state of a SearchView and filtering LiveData with the restored state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, searchview

I'm using a `SearchView` in my layout to let a user search for categories.
The problem that arises is when restoring state when i navigate away from the
fragment and come back (`View` gets restored)...

What happens is that the `onQueryTextChange` method gets called
from the `SearchView's` `setOnQueryTextListener` with its last entered query, before `submitList`() is called. The result of this is an empty list instead of a filtered list.

The question: How can I make sure `onQueryTextChange` gets called (with restored state) after `submitlist` has been called, without breaking anything

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            (binding.rvCategories.adapter as CategoriesAdapter).filter.filter(newText)
            return false
        }
    })

    viewModel.categories.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        categoryAdapter.submitList(it)
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. I want the SearchView to restore its state and filter the list after it has received its data. I have tried filtering using my `ViewModel` but the problem in this scenario is that i can't use a `SwitchMap` function for the categories `LiveData` because i already have one.

The only 'solution' I have now is to disable the `SearchView` from restoring its state by doing:

```
searchView.isSaveEnabled = false
searchView.isSaveFromParentEnabled = false
```

But that's not really what i want because I'd like the fragment to restore its state correctly

My `ViewModel`:

```
    private val _rootCategory = MutableLiveData<Category?>()
    val rootCategory: LiveData<Category?>
        get() = _rootCategory

    val categories = rootCategory.switchMap {
        loadData(it)
    }

    private fun loadData(rootCategory: Category?): LiveData<List<Category>> {
        return if (rootCategory == null) {
        //No root category, retrieve root categories
        databaseManager.getRootCategories().asLiveData().map {
            removeDefaultCategory(it)
        }
    } else {
        //Root category, retrieve its subcategories
        databaseManager.getRootCategories().asLiveData().map {
            it.first { c -> c == rootCategory }.subCategories
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So when you navigate to another fragment and return back, `viewModel.categories.observe` doesn't execute?

Comment: it does execute, but the timing is the issue. onQueryTextChange gets called with the restored filterquery before submitlist is called, so it basically filters an empty list

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is better if you filter `categories` in `ViewModel` and then submit the filtered data to `categoryAdapter` instead of directly calling `filter` in `CategoriesAdapter`. This way, every time your view gets restored you have the latest data from `categories` LiveData gets submitted to `categoriesAdapter` and also you applying `Unidirectional Data Flow`. Something like this

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            // notify viewModel of text change
            viewModel.onQueryTextChange(newText ?: "")
            return false
        }
    })

    viewModel.categories.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        categoryAdapter.submitList(it)
    }
}
```

then in your `ViewModel`

```
fun onQueryTextChange(newQuery: String) {
    // get filtered categories from database or
    // filter categories list and then emit the
    // new list using categories LiveData
}
```

Comment: I have tried something like this, but i have no idea how to filter the categories list because i'm also relying on the rootcategory variable in my viewmodel to check if subcategories should be retrieved instead of rootcategories

Comment: Since I don't know the problem you are trying to solve and how you trigger `loadData` for getting subcategories, it's kinda hard to help you with that